# Red Hat seeing all processes and detail information about them

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, ps

im on a red hat server and i did ps -a and see all running processes.

```
CMD> ps -a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1857 pts/5    00:00:00 ps
 9011 pts/1    00:00:00 su
 9097 pts/1    00:00:00 csh
20515 pts/1    00:00:00 su
20658 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

How can I get more information on these processes so i know, per say, which program name is associated with these pids?

Comment: You just need a few more args.  Try 'ps aux' or 'pstree' may be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to use `ps`, then you can use:

```
ps aux
```

Explanation of the parameters:

- `a`: lists processes spawned by any user (by default it only displays your processes)
- `x`: lists processes without a [TTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) too, for example processes started by automatic runscripts and/or internal system processes
- `u`: displays more information, like the user who started the process, CPU/MEM usage and much more things.

You can find more information about `ps` in its [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps). There's plenty of stuff.

If you prefer a more an interactive solution (which allows you to kill processes, sort them or more), you can try [top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29), which looks like this:
[image: top]

Or [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/), which is easier to use and looks really cool:
[image: htop]